# Offline MBTiles map for Android

Tags: mapbox, android, osmdroid, qgis-android

I would like to be able to open in MBTiles a map format for my android device.

I know to open this file with ArcGIS Android SDK but does anybody know how to open this from open source library, such as from Mapbox,osmdroid...etc?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout MAPLY/whirly globe open source map toolkit for iOS/android.http://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/  . It supports MBTILES, GEOJSON, shape files, vector tiles, WMS, WMTS, XYZ, TMS. MAPBOX, AND MUCH MORE

Comment: I've been reading the documentation, GIT repo, and it looks pretty interesting. Do you have any experience with this option? I mean, have you been using it in a production app for Android? My use case is an offline app, with a lot of data to be shown over the map.

Comment: yes we use it for many years in high production use!!! in apps for US Military and NGA and Pilots

Comment: As long as mbtiles or geopackages are Spherical Web Mercator the speed/performance is great.  Vector Tiles mbtiles support is great. check out http://aeroapp.info

Comment: It now supports OGC GeoPackage SQLite GPKG for Raster Tiles and Vector Features with SLD - Style Layer Describer Symbology Encoding

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll give it a chance and see if it's better than my current option (CartoDB).

Answer (score 0):

osmdroid contributor here

Drop the .mbtiles files into /sdcard/osmdroid/

Discovery should be automatic. "Tile source" names are not applicable for mbtiles in the osmdroid context.

So in theory, if you put the [sample app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.osmdroid) on a device and start it up, you should be looking at whatever tiles are in the .mbtile files

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but I want to put . MBTiles file to my own Android app.

Comment: You should probably check out the wiki for osmdroid then,  step by step directions

Comment: I have tried in android Gradle osmdroid sdk 5.5 but I am not able to see anything in screen if you have any sample pl share ...

Comment: Also see the faq, on osmdroid's wiki. Common issue, usually either permissions or storage availability, or maybe you didn't set the user agent value

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply...I will check and let you know